# \rviz_visual_tools not shown in MarkerArray Topic's

Tags: ros2, c++, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros2 humble. I'm working on the [MoveIt 2 tutorial](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/tutorials/visualizing_in_rviz/visualizing_in_rviz.html).
After creating the [Sourcecode](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials/blob/main/doc/tutorials/visualizing_in_rviz/hello_moveit.cpp) i have to add the RvizVisualToolsGui and the MarkerArray.
In the MarkerArray i have to change the topic to \rviz_visual_tools.

Unfortunately it dosen't show this topic in the drop down menu.
I can just choose between \visualization_marker_array, \display_cost_source and \display_contacts.

After doing the step by step tutorial i just copied the the whole sourcecode but there is still the same problem.

How can i solve this?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407729/%5Crviz_visual_tools-not-shown-in-markerarray-topic%27s/) by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2022-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to type the Topic in manually. (without using the dropdown menu)

This worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) with karma: 42 on 2022-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0